# Layouts overlapping one above the another while using include layout in android

Tags: android, layout, include

I have 3 layouts, main.xml, layout1.xml, layout2.xml.

layout1.xml has around 10 text fields and layout2.xml has 4 buttons

In main.xml I am callling other 2 layouts as

```
<include layout="@layout/data_layout"/>     
<include layout="@layout/button_layout"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@layout/data_layout" />
```

Now my problem is both layout1.xml and layout2.xml are overlapping one above the another.
But I need layout2.xml has to start at the bottom of layout1.xml

Any Ideas on this one?

Main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/nieTxtState"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
     android:text="@string/state"
     android:textSize="14dp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/nieTxtTNState"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nieTxtState"
     android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
     android:text="@string/tnState"
     android:textSize="14dp" />

 <include 
     layout="@layout/data_layout"/>     
 <include 
     layout="@layout/button_layout"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@layout/data_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

data_layout.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nieTxtState"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/state"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nieTxtTNState"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nieTxtState"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/tnState"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewDistrict"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/nieTxtTNState"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/district"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnDistrict"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewDistrict"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewHSS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spnDistrict"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/hssSite"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnHSS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewHSS"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spnHSS"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/age"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTxtAge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewAge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:hint="@string/hintAge"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewLiteracy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtTxtAge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/literacyStatus"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnLiteracy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewLiteracy"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewPregnancy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spnLiteracy"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/currentPregnancy"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnPregnancy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewPregnancy"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewReferralSource"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spnPregnancy"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/referralSource"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnReferralSource"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewReferralSource"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewResidence"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spnReferralSource"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/residecnePlace"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnResidence"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewResidence"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewDurationOfStay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spnResidence"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/DurationOfStay"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTxtDurationOfYear"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewDurationOfStay"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/hintYear"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTxtDurationOfMonth"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewDurationOfStay"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edtTxtDurationOfYear"
        android:hint="@string/hintMonth"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewRespOccupation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtTxtDurationOfYear"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/respondentOccupation"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnRespOccupation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewRespOccupation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewSpouseOccupation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spnRespOccupation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/spouseOccupation"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnSpouseOccupation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewSpouseOccupation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewSpouseResidesAwayFromWife"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spnSpouseOccupation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/spouseResidesAwayFromWife"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnSpouseResidesAwayFromWife"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewSpouseResidesAwayFromWife"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

button_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ancSaveBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/upload"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ancAddNewBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ancSaveBtn"
    android:text="@string/addNew"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ancClearBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ancAddNewBtn"
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ancExitBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ancClearBtn"
    android:text="@string/exit"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use vertical leniar layout as the parent in main.xml i hope it will help

Comment: user relative layout so you can set them "Bottom" / "Top".

Comment: @droidhot Thanks for the reply. Tried both but still the same problem.

Comment: @StyleMe : I am using relative layout only

Comment: can you post the code for us so we know what you have done so far! just update your question with ur layouts and i'm sure we will help you much better .

Comment: @shrikant the problem is when included the layout wont be resized(for eg with weight) as its inflated from another layout you can put them in a scrol view's chield layout then it wont overlap probably

Comment: @StyleMe : Please check my edited question. I have posted all the layouts.

Comment: okay. i'm going to see it now. give me five minutes. !

Comment: @Shrikant do check my edited code below. already modified it. and the button layout already on the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to do some walk around to get the right layout. Please if this is not what you are looking feel free to post here a screen shot that you would like to archive

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_content_1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_content_2"
        layout="@layout/top_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_content_2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_content_1"
        layout="@layout/data_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_content_3"
        layout="@layout/button_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

button_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ancSaveBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="upload"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ancAddNewBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="new"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ancClearBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="clear"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ancExitBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="edit"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

data_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nieTxtState"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:text="state"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nieTxtTNState"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nieTxtState"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:text="tnState"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewDistrict"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/nieTxtTNState"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="district"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnDistrict"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewDistrict"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewHSS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spnDistrict"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="hssSite"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnHSS"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewHSS"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewAge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spnHSS"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="age"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtTxtAge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewAge"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:hint="hintAge"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewLiteracy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtTxtAge"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="literacyStatus"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnLiteracy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewLiteracy"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPregnancy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spnLiteracy"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="currentPregnancy"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnPregnancy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewPregnancy"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewReferralSource"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spnPregnancy"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="referralSource"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnReferralSource"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewReferralSource"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewResidence"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spnReferralSource"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="residecnePlace"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnResidence"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewResidence"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewDurationOfStay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spnResidence"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="DurationOfStay"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtTxtDurationOfYear"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewDurationOfStay"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:hint="hintYear"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtTxtDurationOfMonth"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewDurationOfStay"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edtTxtDurationOfYear"
                android:hint="hintMonth"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewRespOccupation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtTxtDurationOfYear"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="respondentOccupation"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnRespOccupation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewRespOccupation"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewSpouseOccupation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spnRespOccupation"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="spouseOccupation"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnSpouseOccupation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewSpouseOccupation"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewSpouseResidesAwayFromWife"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spnSpouseOccupation"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="spouseResidesAwayFromWife"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnSpouseResidesAwayFromWife"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtViewSpouseResidesAwayFromWife"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

top_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nieTxtState"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="123434343434"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nieTxtTNState"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nieTxtState"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="1233434343"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Shrikant i just update my post for you. let me know if this what you are looking for or not

Comment: Thanks a ton Festus. This is what exactly I was looking for. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<include layout="@layout/data_layout"/>     
<include layout="@layout/button_layout"         
     android:layout_below="@+id/your_data_layout_id" />
```

Comment: Please check my edited question. I have posted all the layouts

Answer (score 1):

here is your main layout. 
copy replace. and see the changes ! please see i'v deleted some things that ain't in my working place. so see what i deleted from ur code such as "strings" and add them back.

```
  EDIT-----------------------------
```

don't forget to accept the answer if its what you seek :). 
here is the edited part

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>
<include
    android:layout_above="@+id/frame"
    layout="@layout/data_layout" />

<FrameLayout android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/frame">
    <include layout="@layout/button_layout"/>
</FrameLayout>
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/nieTxtState"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="14dp"
     android:text="JOOOO" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/nieTxtTNState"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nieTxtState"
     android:textSize="14dp"
     android:text="JOOOO" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Ya this is what I was looking for, but 2 small isuues with this. 1) Can't scroll the last spinner, it overlaps with buttons. 2) The texts in the main_layout.xml (JOOOO & JOOOO in this case) overlaps on other fields after scrolling. I got the solution from Festus Tamakloe. Anyway thanks a lot for spending your time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must include layout height and width to use "layout_below" otherwise the below request will be ignored.

```
<include layout="@layout/data_layout"/>     
<include layout="@layout/button_layout"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@layout/data_layout"
     android:layout_height="240dp" (Use @dimen as best practise)
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<include 
android:id="@+id/first"
layout="@layout/data_layout"
/>     
<include layout="@layout/button_layout"
android:layout_below="@+id/first"
/>
```

I hope,it will be helpful.